# how to use $var$i in shell

Tags: bash, shell

```
domaindir1='/somedir/somedir1'
domaindir2='/somedir/somedir2'
domaindir3='/somedir/somedir3'
domaindir4='/somedir/somedir4'
for i in {1..4}
do
  echo $domaindir$i  
done
```

So what I want in output is

```
somedir/somedir1
somedir/somedir2
somedir/somedir3
somedir/somedir4
```

but I am getting

```
domaindir1
domaindir2
domaindir3
domaindir4
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you are on bash, why not using arrays?

```
domaindir[1]='/somedir/somedir1'
domaindir[2]='/somedir/somedir2'
domaindir[3]='/somedir/somedir3'
domaindir[4]='/somedir/somedir4'
for i in {1..4}
do
  echo ${domaindir[i]}
done
```

Or better,

```
for i in "${domaindir[@]}"
do
  echo $i
done
```

this way you don't need to hardcode the array length.